# Getting paginator from react-js-pagination to display on page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, react-redux

I have a react app which is the front end for a shopping site.

I have a products page and I am trying to add pagination from react-js-pagination to the bottom of it so that I do not have to render the entire list of products at once.

I have followed the guidlines on implementing the pagination from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-js-pagination but I still cannot get it to display (the rest of the page displays properly).

Can anybody see why?

Please see my code for the entire page below:

```
import React from 'react';
import Pagination from 'react-js-pagination';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

import changeBrandFilter from '../actions/changeBrandFilter';
import changePriceFilter from '../actions/changePriceFilter';

import CategoryOverview from './CategoryOverview';
import Filter from './Filter';
import ProductsListItem from './ProductsListItem';
import ProductsPageContainerCSS from './ProductsPageContainer.css';

class ProductsPage extends React.Component{
    createCategoryOverview() {
        return this.props.overview.map(overview => {
            return (
                <CategoryOverview 
                    title={overview.title}
                    text={overview.text}
                    image={overview.imageSource}
                    alt={overview.imageAlt}
                />
            )
        })
    }
    createBrandFilterList() {
        return this.props.brandFilters.map(filter => {
            return (
                <Filter
                    key={filter.brand}
                    id={filter.brand}
                    changeFilter={() => this.props.changeBrandFilter(filter)}
                    inuse={filter.inuse}
                    disabled={filter.disabled}
                />
            )
        })
    }
    createPriceRangeFilterList() {
        return this.props.priceRangeFilters.map(filter => {
            return (
                <Filter
                    key={filter.priceRange}
                    id={filter.priceRange}
                    changeFilter={() => this.props.changePriceFilter(filter)}
                    inuse={filter.inuse}
                    disabled={filter.disabled}
                />
            )
        })
    }
    filterDivExtenionToggle () {
            var filterDivExtension = document.querySelector('.filterDivExtension');
            var chevronUp = document.querySelector('#chevronUp');
            var chevronDown = document.querySelector('#chevronDown');
            var icon;
            if (filterDivExtension.style.display === 'block') {
                filterDivExtension.style.display = 'none';
                chevronUp.style.display = 'none';
                chevronDown.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                filterDivExtension.style.display = 'block';
                chevronUp.style.display = 'block';
                chevronDown.style.display = 'none';
            }
    }
    createProductsList() {
        if(this.props.products.length > 0) {
            return this.props.products.map(product =>{
                if (this.props.products.indexOf(product) >= this.state.activePage -1 && this.props.products.indexOf(product) < (this.state.activePage*12)) {
                    return (
                        <ProductsListItem
                            key={product.id}
                            brand={product.brand}
                            model={product.model}
                            price={product.price}
                            image={product.image}
                            link={"/"+this.props.match.params.type+"/"+product.id}
                        />
                    )
                }

            })} else {
                return <div>No products match the filter criteria selected above.</div>
            } 
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {activePage: 1};
    }
    handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
        this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    {this.createCategoryOverview()}
                    <div ClassName="row">
                        <div className= "filterDiv col-12">
                            <div className="iconCrossbar">
                                <i id="chevronDown" className="fa fa-chevron-down" onClick={this.filterDivExtenionToggle}></i>
                                <i id="chevronUp" className="fa fa-chevron-up" onClick={this.filterDivExtenionToggle}></i>
                            </div>
                            <div className="filterDivExtension">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="filtersList col-md-6 col-12">
                                        Filter by Brand:
                                        <div>
                                            {this.createBrandFilterList()}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="filtersList col-md-6 col-12">
                                        Filter by Price Range:
                                        <div>
                                            {this.createPriceRangeFilterList()}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row productsList">
                        {this.createProductsList()}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Pagination 
                    activePage={this.state.activePage}
                    itemsCountPerPage={12}
                    totalItemsCount={this.props.products.length}
                    pageRangeDisplayed={2}
                    onChange={this.handlePageChange}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
};

function mapStateToProps(state , ownProps) {
    let brandFilters = state.brandFilters;
    let filtered_brandFilters = brandFilters;
    filtered_brandFilters = filtered_brandFilters.filter(
        filter => filter.type === ownProps.match.params.type
    )
    let priceRangeFilters = state.priceRangeFilters;
    let filtered_priceRangeFilters = priceRangeFilters;
    filtered_priceRangeFilters = filtered_priceRangeFilters.filter(
        filter => filter.type === ownProps.match.params.type
    )
    let products = state.products;
    let overviews = state.overviews;
    let overview = overviews.filter(
        overview => overview.type === ownProps.match.params.type
    )
    let filtered_products = products;
    filtered_products = filtered_products.filter(
        product => product.type === ownProps.match.params.type //gets type from the the route params and finds products which have type that matches
    )
    let activeBrandFilters = brandFilters.filter(
        item => item.inuse === true
    );
    activeBrandFilters.forEach(filter => {
        filtered_products = filtered_products.filter(
            product => product.brand === filter.brand
        )
    });
    let activePriceRangeFilters = priceRangeFilters.filter(
        item => item.inuse === true
    );
    activePriceRangeFilters.forEach(filter => {
        filtered_products = filtered_products.filter(
            product => product.priceRange === filter.priceRange
        );
    });
    return {
        overview: overview,
        brandFilters: filtered_brandFilters,
        priceRangeFilters: filtered_priceRangeFilters,
        products: filtered_products
    };
};

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({changeBrandFilter: changeBrandFilter, changePriceFilter: changePriceFilter}, dispatch);
};

export const ProductsPageContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(ProductsPage);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't help you with react-js-pagination, on the other hand, I did it very easily using react-prime. [Paginator React Prime](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/paginator). Ok, so, I'll try to explain it to you,
first thing is to understand what this framework gives to us:

you import it:

```
import {Paginator} from 'primereact/components/paginator/Paginator';
```

then probably, you will have a list of components you have to render in order to paginate through it.
On your container component you have to set these values in order for you paginator to work:

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {first: 0, rows: 10};
        this.onPageChange = this.onPageChange.bind(this);
    }

    onPageChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            first: event.first,
            rows: event.rows
        });
    }
```

then you will have the paginator component itself:

```
<Paginator first={this.state.first} rows={this.state.rows} totalRecords={yourcomponentlist.length} onPageChange={this.onPageChange}></Paginator>
```

Now let's analyse it, we have a number of rows showing up in each page (rows), and the relative number of the first line to be displayed(first). so, you can have your list of components working with paginator using the slice javascript method to render only the components you wish after paginating.

```
<tbody>
    {
        this.props.components.slice(this.state.first, this.state.first + 
        this.state.rows).map((component) => {
            return <ComponentListItem key={component._id} {...componentData} />;
         })
     }
</tbody>
```

That's it, I hope I was able to help you understand how this paginator works, react-prime is a great toolbelt, it has many themes for your design as well, I was very happy using it!

Comment: Thanks for the very clear and detailed instructions Leonel! This seems just as straight forward as react-js-pagination seemed to be. My only question is how can I install this? I want to add it to my own app and not install an entirely new one to extract a single component from it as seems to be the case here?

Comment: Yes, to use react-prime you have to install it all. I think there's no other way, if you know some other way, please let me know!

Comment: Ok so I went back and tried my luck with react-js-pagination again.

As it turned out it wasn't displaying because I hadn't applied a class to it even though the documentation states that this is not 'required'.

even though I managed to display it I still could not get it to run the handlePage function without the need to do a whole load of extra functions myself (if that was even possible!). So instead I made my own version of pagination using just 'next' and 'prev' buttons. it works just as I would wish it to. I am happy to share my code if anyone feels it would be helpful?

Comment: post it here, it would be nice to use a single component instead of an entire framework full of components!

Comment: Ok, I will post it as an answer to my initial question since I must paste my code in...

Answer (score 1):

Ok so if you read my comments on Leonel's answer you will see that I did manage to get the paginator from react-js-paginator to display but could still not get it to work.

I made my own custom basic paginator component instead.

please find the paginator component that i made below:

```
import React from 'react';

class Paginaton extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="pagination">
                    <button id="prevPage" className="btn" disabled={this.props.disabled1} onClick={() => this.props.onclick1()}>prev</button>
                    <button id="nextPage" className="btn" disabled={this.props.disabled2} onClick={() => this.props.onclick2()}>next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Paginaton;
```

As you can see this is just a prev button and a next button.

I then, in the container component, made sure that only the button which was required to be active was shown as active and the button that was not required to be active was shown as inactive. this made sure that prev was not a clickable option when on the first page of products and next was not a clickable option when on the last page of products.

I also made sure to add a 'key' prop to the component that was unique to the route that the component was displayed on. This was needed because my pagination relies on a state that I have set in the component which declares the 'activePage' so that when I would go on to a page of products of another type (from kits products to tanks products for example), the component would remount (since both routes render the same component, with the products rendered being decided by the route parameters) and the state would revert to its initial state ({activePage: 1}).

Please see the container component below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

import changeBrandFilter from '../actions/changeBrandFilter';
import changePriceFilter from '../actions/changePriceFilter';

import CategoryOverview from './CategoryOverview';
import Filter from './Filter';
import ProductsListItem from './ProductsListItem';
import ProductsPageContainerCSS from './ProductsPageContainer.css';
import Pagination from './Pagination';

class ProductsPage extends React.Component{
    createCategoryOverview() {
        let i = 1;
        return this.props.overview.map(overview => {
            i++
            return (
                <CategoryOverview 
                    key={"catOverview"+i} //each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop
                    title={overview.title}
                    text={overview.text}
                    image={overview.imageSource}
                    alt={overview.imageAlt}
                />
            )
        })
    }
    createBrandFilterList() {
        let i = 1;
        return this.props.brandFilters.map(filter => {
            i++
            return (
                <Filter
                    key={filter.brand+i+"brand"}
                    name={this.props.match.params.type + "brandFilter"} //so that each seperate group of radio buttons (filters) refer only to each other. (the name is shared within each group)
                    id={filter.brand}
                    changeFilterResetPageNumber={() => {this.props.changeBrandFilter(filter); this.handlePageChange(1)}} //without page reset would often get no products displayed on filter application due to the activePage state remaining at the page that was active at the time of filter application
                    inuse={filter.inuse}
                />
            )
        })
    }
    createPriceRangeFilterList() {
        let i = 1;
        return this.props.priceRangeFilters.map(filter => {
            i++
            return (
                <Filter
                    key={filter.priceRange+i+"priceRange"}
                    name={this.props.match.params.type + "priceFilter"} 
                    id={filter.priceRange}
                    changeFilterResetPageNumber={() => {this.props.changePriceFilter(filter); this.handlePageChange(1)}}
                    inuse={filter.inuse}
                />
            )
        })
    }
    filterDivExtenionToggle () {
            var filterDivExtension = document.querySelector('.filterDivExtension');
            var chevronUp = document.querySelector('#chevronUp');
            var chevronDown = document.querySelector('#chevronDown');
            var icon;
            if (filterDivExtension.style.display === 'block') {
                filterDivExtension.style.display = 'none';
                chevronUp.style.display = 'none';
                chevronDown.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                filterDivExtension.style.display = 'block';
                chevronUp.style.display = 'block';
                chevronDown.style.display = 'none';
            }
    }
    createProductsList() {
        if(this.props.products.length > 0) {
            return this.props.products.map(product =>{
                if (this.props.products.indexOf(product) >= (this.state.activePage*12) - 12 && this.props.products.indexOf(product) < (this.state.activePage*12)) { //render the 12 (number of products per page) products that correspond to the current (active) page
                    return (
                        <ProductsListItem
                            key={product.id}
                            brand={product.brand}
                            model={product.model}
                            price={product.price}
                            image={product.image}
                            link={"/"+this.props.match.params.type+"/"+product.id}
                        />
                    )
                }

            })} else {
                return <div>No products match the filter criteria selected above.</div>
            } 
    }
    state = {
        activePage: 1
    }
    handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
        this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});
    }
    createPagination() {
        if (this.props.products.length > 12) {
            if (this.props.products.length > this.state.activePage * 12 && this.state.activePage > 1) { //if there are products following AND preceding the current page
                return (
                    <Pagination 
                        onclick1={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage - 1)}
                        onclick2={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage + 1)}
                        disabled1={false}
                        disabled2={false}
                    />
                )
            } else if (this.props.products.length > this.state.activePage * 12) { //if there are only products following the current page
                return (
                    <Pagination 
                        onclick1={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage - 1)}
                        onclick2={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage + 1)}
                        disabled1={true}
                        disabled2={false}
                    />
                ) 
            } else if (this.state.activePage > 1) { //if there are only products preceding the current page
                return (
                    <Pagination 
                        onclick1={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage - 1)}
                        onclick2={() => this.handlePageChange(this.state.activePage + 1)}
                        disabled1={false}
                        disabled2={true}
                    />
                ) 
            }

        }
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    {this.createCategoryOverview()}
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className= "filterDiv col-12">
                            <div className="iconCrossbar">
                                <i id="chevronDown" className="fa fa-chevron-down" onClick={this.filterDivExtenionToggle}></i>
                                <i id="chevronUp" className="fa fa-chevron-up" onClick={this.filterDivExtenionToggle}></i>
                            </div>
                            <div className="filterDivExtension">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="filtersList col-md-6 col-12">
                                        Filter by Brand:
                                        <div>
                                            {this.createBrandFilterList()}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="filtersList col-md-6 col-12">
                                        Filter by Price Range:
                                        <div>
                                            {this.createPriceRangeFilterList()}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row productsList">
                        {this.createProductsList()}
                    </div>
                    {this.createPagination()}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

function mapStateToProps(state , ownProps) {
    let brandFilters = state.brandFilters;
    let filtered_brandFilters = brandFilters;
    filtered_brandFilters = filtered_brandFilters.filter(
        filter => filter.type === ownProps.match.params.type //gets type from the the route params and finds products which have type that matches
    )
    let priceRangeFilters = state.priceRangeFilters;
    let filtered_priceRangeFilters = priceRangeFilters;
    filtered_priceRangeFilters = filtered_priceRangeFilters.filter(
        filter => filter.type === ownProps.match.params.type
    )
    let overviews = state.overviews;
    let overview = overviews.filter(
        overview => overview.type === ownProps.match.params.type
    )
    let products = state.products;
    let filtered_products = products;
    filtered_products = filtered_products.filter(
        product => product.type === ownProps.match.params.type
    )
    let activeBrandFilters = filtered_brandFilters.filter(
        item => item.inuse === true
    );
    activeBrandFilters.forEach(filter => {
        if (filter.brand != "ALL") {
            filtered_products = filtered_products.filter(
                product => product.brand === filter.brand
            )
        }
    });
    let activePriceRangeFilters = filtered_priceRangeFilters.filter(
        item => item.inuse === true
    );
    activePriceRangeFilters.forEach(filter => {
        if (filter.priceRange != "ALL") {
            filtered_products = filtered_products.filter(
                product => product.priceRange === filter.priceRange
            );
        }
    });
    let key = ownProps.match.params.type;
    return {
        overview: overview,
        brandFilters: filtered_brandFilters,
        priceRangeFilters: filtered_priceRangeFilters,
        products: filtered_products,
        key: key //a change of key property means the component remounts. this was needed so that when on a second page of products (state is activePage: 2) and switching to a 'page' with products type that does not have a second page (uses same components but displays different type of products), no products would be displayed because the component did not remount and thh state remained the same (activePage did not reset to 1)
    };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({changeBrandFilter: changeBrandFilter, changePriceFilter: changePriceFilter}, dispatch);
};

export const ProductsPageContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductsPage);
```